# Can't find liblapack.so.3 in ubuntu 12.04

Tags: matlab, ubuntu, lapack

When I ran a matlab code in ubuntu 12.04, an error occurred:

> liblapack.so.3: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

Then I installed `lapack` and `libatlas`, but only found `liblapack.so.3gf` instead of `liblapack.so.3` in `/usr/lib`. Which package should I install to get `liblapack.so.3`?

Comment: https://packages.debian.org/search?searchon=contents&keywords=liblapack.so.3&mode=path&suite=stable&arch=any

Comment: @tripleee Thanks, problem solved by installing liblapack3 manyally.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Take a look at this thread:

[liblapack.so file](https://askubuntu.com/questions/300542/liblapack-so-file)

You will basically have to manually download and install a package (follow the links from the aforementioned thread) fro Ubuntu 12.
  Another thing that I suggest to try is to create a link to "liblapack.so.3gf" like this:

```
sudo ln -s /usr/lib/liblapack.so.3gf /usr/lib/liblapack.so.3
```

There are more than one distribution of the library and the implementation might differ.

Answer (score 2):

try

```
sudo apt-get install -y liblapacke.so.3
```

[ for AIMET installation ]

Comment: Yes, Thank you .  I'm also installing AIMET.